# The "portal_homepage" route must have code to run when it matches error

Tags: php, symfony, routes, silex, matcher

I am working on a project locally and get a LogicException thrown when trying to access the homepage. The back-end login and front-end login pages work fine, I can login to the back-end without a problem, however the front-end side of the project doesn't work for me(homepage included). Back-end acknowledges the fact that I had logged in to my account, however every time I try to log in I get the same exception thrown. It seems to work for everybody else, except for me and nobody knows the reason.

Please check the image in [this link](https://prntscr.com/ncnxph) 
   (I lack the reputation to post images).

Answer (score 0):

Seems `homepage` handler is empty and doesn't return `Response`

```
$app->get('/', function() use($app) {
    return 'Portal homepage';
})->bind('portal_homepage');
```